# Unable to change ssl settings for custom domain on app engine

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

When I attempt to change the ssl setting for my custom domains, the dash board were unable to load the "Select SSL serving mode", and the save button is disabled.

I've also noticed in Inspector that it was trying to access 'https://console.cloud.google.com/m/sslCertificate?certificateId=xxxx' but has a 404 response.

Am I the only one receiving this error or is this a bug on the dashboard?

Comment: Normally, the SSL certificates page of the Developers Console is accessible from [https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/certificates](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/certificates).  What URL were you viewing?  You mention seeing the Inspector trying to access https://console.cloud.google.com/n/sslCertificate.  Assuming you mean the network panel of the Chrome Developer Tools, what behavior on the page was causing it to request that URL?  Can you provide a screenshot of that page?

Answer (score 1):

The `URL` that you provided in your question is valid, however receiving `404 error` for your `URI` could be temporary and caused by your web browser or Internet proxy caching. Try clearing the cashed data and open a fresh Cloud Console.